# Realtime update of Android and iOS from web server?

Tags: android, ios, facebook, real-time

I'm trying to synchronise my android/ios app with the server.

My app allows user to update their profile and I would like to implement something like when user update their profile in the website, then user will get live update in their app or maybe a indicator like Facebook "New Stories" bar that allow user to touch and get their update.

I have read this [SO Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13371405/ios-android-realtime-news-feed-implementation) but I wish I can know more in details or any alternative way on achieving this feature

Comment: For Android and iOS you could use Urban Airship notifications

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend that you check out NodeJS (http://nodejs.org/) and Socket.io (http://socket.io/) for your Use Case, though it might not be ideal for the mobile environment.

See an overview of different "real time technologies" here: http://www.leggetter.co.uk/real-time-web-technologies-guide/realtime-web-technology-transport-mechanisms