# NGINX reverse proxy always closes the websocket after 1 minute with open internet connections

Tags: android, nginx, websocket, reverse-proxy

nginx -V output

```
built by gcc 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3) (GCC)
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --prefix=/etc/nginx --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --lock-path=/var/run/nginx.lock --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/client_temp --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/proxy_temp --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/fastcgi_temp --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/uwsgi_temp --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/scgi_temp --user=nginx --group=nginx --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_addition_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_flv_module --with-http_mp4_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_random_index_module --with-http_secure_link_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module --with-file-aio --with-ipv6 --with-cc-opt='-O2 -g -pipe -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic'
```

The NGINX configuration

```
upstream websocknodes{
 server 192.168.1.2:7070; 
}
location /mywebsocket/server {
    proxy_pass http://192.168.1.2:7070/mywebsocket/server;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_next_upstream error timeout;
    proxy_connect_timeout 2;
    proxy_read_timeout 300s;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    #proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade "websocket";
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
}
```

**The web-socket connection established from 3rd party clients gets closed in 1 minutes in case of normal 3G internet connections and modem based internet**

**But it works properly inside the local intranet**

**If the internet source WIFI hotspot is a lower version android OS 4.0.4 does it makes the websocket timeout and incompatible?**

Can anyone help

----EDIT-----

I assume this can also be related to [WebSockets over a 3G connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5557776/websockets-over-a-3g-connection)

Can anyone confirm please

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem. The reason is that NGINX doesn't support CONNECT because this is reverse proxy server http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/websocket.html

Comment: Did you some resolve the issue?

Comment: Has this been solved?

Comment: I don't think so